# Redirect from one page to another not working

Tags: go, templates, go-templates, go-html-template

I am trying to Insert the scan results using the Scan func and once done I want to redirect to show results which are nothing but a select query to the inserts done ever. Both functions are working properly when tested separately. Is this not the correct way to redirect from the first page to the next?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    dbDriver := "mysql"
    dbUser := "root"
    dbPass := "root"
    dbName := "test"
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@/"+dbName+"?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return db
}

var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("form/*"))
var hostnameInput string

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    http.HandleFunc("/show", Show)

    lerr := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil) // setting listening port
    if lerr != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", lerr)
    }

}

func Insert(hostname string, ports []int) {
    db := dbConn()

    // INSERT INTO DB
    // prepare
    stmt, e := db.Prepare("insert into nmap_reports(reported_at,  host_address) values ( ?, ?)")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }

    //execute
    res, er := stmt.Exec(time.Now(), hostname)
    if er != nil {
        log.Fatal(er)
    }

    for _, v := range ports {
        insForm, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO nmap_report_ports(nmap_report_id,port) VALUES (?,?)")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        id, fail := res.LastInsertId()
        if fail != nil {
            log.Fatal(fail)
        }
        _, er := insForm.Exec(id, v)
        if er != nil {
            log.Fatal(er)
        }
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
func Select(hostname string) []Result {
    db := dbConn()

    // query all data
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT nm.nmap_report_id, nm.host_address,nm.reported_at,GROUP_CONCAT(port) AS `Ports` FROM nmap_reports nm left join  nmap_report_ports nrp on nm.nmap_report_id = nrp.nmap_report_id where nm.host_address = ? group by nm.nmap_report_id order by nmap_report_id desc")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rows, er := stmt.Query(hostname)
    if er != nil {
        log.Fatal(er)
    }

    // declare empty result variable
    var resultI = Result{}

    // iterate over rows
    resultSet := make([]Result, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        e := rows.Scan(&resultI.ReportId, &resultI.Hostname, &resultI.Date, &resultI.Ports)
        if e != nil {
            log.Fatal(er)
        }
        resultSet = append(resultSet, resultI)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    return resultSet
}

type Result struct {
    ReportId int       `json:"reportId"`
    Hostname string    `json:"hostname"`
    Date     time.Time `json:"date"`
    Ports    string    `json:"ports"`
}

func Show(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    data := Select(hostnameInput)
    temp, temperr := template.ParseFiles("form/show.tmpl")
    if temperr != nil {
        log.Fatal(temperr)
    }

    temp.ExecuteTemplate(w, "show", data)

}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("form/input.tmpl")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        //if r.Method == "POST" {
        r.ParseForm()

        fmt.Println("hostname:", r.Form["hname"])

        var rxHostIP = regexp.MustCompile("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$|^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$")
        hostnameInput = strings.Join(r.Form["hname"], "")
        fmt.Println("hnmae is:" + hostnameInput)
        if !rxHostIP.MatchString(hostnameInput) {
            w.WriteHeader(400)
            w.Write([]byte("Invalid Ip/hostname"))
        }

        command := []string{"nmap", "-p", "1-1000"}
        command = append(command, r.Form["hname"]...)
        finalcommand := strings.Join(command, " ")
        fmt.Println(finalcommand)
        cmd := exec.Command(`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, "/c", finalcommand)
        cmdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
        cmd.Stdout = cmdOutput

        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        check := string(cmdOutput.Bytes())

        re := regexp.MustCompile(`([0-9]+)./`)

        stringArr := re.FindAllString(check, -1)

        intArr := make([]int, 0)

        for _, v := range stringArr {
            n := strings.Replace(v, "/", "", -1)

            i, cerr := strconv.Atoi(n)
            if cerr != nil {
                log.Fatal(cerr)
            }
            intArr = append(intArr, i)
        }

        Insert(hostnameInput, intArr)
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/show", 301)
}
```

Trying to redirect from login page to show page using

```
http.Redirect(w, r, "/show", 301)
```

Comment: Does your template specify form `method="post"`? `http.Redirect(w, r, "/show", 301)` is correct way to do redirect and will indeed send redirect header. Also it is not wise to run `nmap` like this as if it runs too long http response will time out. I recommend to debug on smaller body of code like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/5hFafn4DZOl) (will not run in Go Playground) and then once redirect works add the real functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think the redirect code is fine. There might be something going inside the `login` handler that prevents the redirect from happening.

I've annotated and modified some parts of the `login` handler below, if it might be helpful to you.

```
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        // note#1: don't ignore the error
        t, err := template.ParseFiles("form/input.tmpl")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // note#2: check the error
        err = t.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    } else {
        var err error
        // note#3: check the error
        err = r.ParseForm()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // ...
        // other code, omitted for brevity
        // ...
    }

    // note#4: this is fine if you intend to redirect all the request,
    // regardless of the method, to the `/show` endpoint
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/show", 301)
}
```